# Reactor-Netty: unexpected message type: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf

Tags: project-reactor, reactor-netty

I have an HttpServer an an HttpClient. If I make use of Netty's HttpServerCodec and HttpObjectAggregator on either side I get the error.

Server code

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(opts -> opts.listen(8092).afterChannelInit(channelInit -> {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = channelInit.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
    pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(64*1024));
}));
server.newRouter(routes -> {
    routes.post("/xmlvend", postHandler());
}).block(Duration.ofSeconds(30));

BiFunction<? super HttpServerRequest, ? super HttpServerResponse, ? extends Publisher<Void>> postHandler() {
    return (req, resp) -> {
        req.requestHeaders().entries()
           .forEach(entry -> log.debug(String.format("header [%s=>%s]", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())));
        return resp.sendString(req.receive().asByteArray().take(1).log("received").flatMap(data -> {
            return Flux.just("Hello");
        }));
    };
}
```

Client

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.create(opts -> opts.connect(host, port).poolResources(pool).afterChannelInit(serverEndPoint));
ByteBuf reqContent = getTestRequest();
DefaultFullHttpRequest reqHeader = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.POST, url, reqContent);
Mono<HttpClientResponse> rsp = client.request(HttpMethod.POST, url, (req) -> req.chunkedTransfer(true).addHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString(reqHeader.content().capacity())).sendHeaders().send(Flux.just(reqContent)/*clientRequest -> clientRequest.onNext(reqHeader.content())*/));
rsp.subscribe().block();
```

serverEndPoint also contains the HttpServerCodec and ObjectAggregator.
I have tried using the HttpClientCodec, using nothing in the pipeline/s
tried sending the DefaultFullHttpRequest.
Either I get the exception or only 1024 bytes is read on the client side.
I am needing to send a chunked request that is more than 1024bytes.

Thanks

Comment: removing the HttpServerCodec in the HttpServer.create stopped this issue but opened up another - 
I receive this data, it is printed to the console, but it appears that the ByteBuf has no array.

ByteBufUtil.getBytes and ByteBufUtil.prettyHexDump comes up emptyreading the PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.